# Elegant way to make a column based array row based

Tags: php, html, arrays, tabular

I currently have a array where each field contains another array with the actual data I want to display. This array is column based, meaning each field is one column.

As far as I can tell, to render that data in html I would need to flip it so that it is row based meaning I would need to go through each field and each item of the array in that field and generate a new array where now each item would be a row.

I am wondering if there is a cleaner and more elegant solution than having two nested for loops. Here is some sample data:

```
$data = array(
    'ID1' => array('Column 1', 'Cell 1', 'Cell 2', 'Cell3')
    'ID2' => array('Column 2', 'Cell 1', 'Cell 2', 'Cell3'),    
    'ID3' => array('Column 3', 'Cell 1', 'Cell 2'),    
);
```

The final goal is to produce a HTML table (probably using divs rather than table/tr/td)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any built in method but you can easily flip an array like this.
I first find the max number of columns then loop the array with index in a for loop and use that in array_column.
I also omit 'column' in this code.
I suppose you don't need that.
If you do need it change the for loop to start at 0.

```
//Find lenghts of columns
Foreach($data as $column){
    $count[] = count($column);
}
$count = max($count);// get the max number of columns

For($i=1;$i<$count;$i++){
    $arr["row" . $i] = array_column($data, $i);
}

Var_dump($arr);
```

You can try it here, I use other cell names just to make sure I see that it does correct.

https://3v4l.org/vEu4r

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the array_column function. This makes things easier